# is it possible to emulate the real person as same as possible when using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cloudflare

I am using selenium to do some automatic test, rencently our security team add the cloudflare turnstile that make my automatic test process failed, everything works fine except the human verification:

[image]

I have changed the selenium to undetect google driver seems did not work for this. is it possible to recover the human verify process? what should I do to recover it? this is the Python code I am using right now:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from apps.visa.browser.visa_book import VisaBook
import urllib3
import shutil
import os

urllib3.disable_warnings()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")
    src_file = os.path.join(home_dir, "chrome/base/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip")
    dist_file = os.path.join(home_dir, "chrome/chromedriver/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip")
    shutil.copy(src_file, dist_file)
    driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    driver = uc.Chrome(
        options=options,
        headless=False,
        use_subprocess=False,
        chrome_driver_zip_path=dist_file,
        driver_service=driver_service)
    wait: WebDriverWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
    driver.get("https://example.com/login")
    visa_book = VisaBook()
    visa_book.login(wait, driver)
```